# Where can I put the CUDA DLLs for Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

On my work computer, I do not have permissions to install new software, edit `PATH`, etc. I have Python installed to local folder (and everything works, including `pip` to install and update packages. But, I cannot install the Cuda Computing Toolkit.

On another computer that I have those permissions, I have tensorflow installed, verified, and by using ProcessExplorer I know what 3 DLLs I need to have installed for tensorflow to work with my Python app.

Typically, when I have this problem, I have found it is acceptable to install DLLs in the local path relative to the binary loading/requiring them; for instance: I put the Visual Studio runtime DLL in the same folder as `python.exe` and I do not need to actually run the installer.

However, I cannot figure out where the cuda DLLs need to go relative to tensorflow for them to be loaded. I have searched the source with no luck. I have set breakpoints in a Python debugger with no luck. Can anybody point me to where the DLLs need to go, or at least where they are loaded?

Comment: You can either put the DLLs at any directory that is part of the PATH environment/user variable (I suggest to create a dedicated folder for that) or you can just place the DLLs in the working directory of the application (not recommended as it's less reusable)

Comment: I ended up putting the DLLs in the same directory as python.exe and that worked. However, you are correct about it being less usable. And, if the working directory is wrong, it doesn't work. To overcome that, I just made a shortcut to execute the python script from the proper working directory. It's ugly, but given the restrictions on my work computer, it got the job done.